# Generic advanced Delegate.CreateDelegate using expression trees

Tags: c#, expression-trees

As far as I know the standard [`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) which allows to create a delegate by using reflection, doesn't allow doing something as follows when the first parameter of `method` isn't **exactly** of type `object`.

```
public class Bleh
{
    public void SomeMethod( string s ) { }
}
...
object bleh = new Bleh(); 
MethodInfo method = bleh.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod");    
// Starting from here, all knowledge about Bleh is unknown. 
// Only bleh and method are available.
Action<object> a = (Action<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof( Action<object> ), bleh, method );
```

Which is why I now have an implementation which allows the following:

```
Action<object> compatibleExecute =
    DelegateHelper.CreateCompatibleDelegate<Action<object>>( bleh, method );
```

`method` can be any method, with or without return type, and with as many parameters as desired. I need to create an `Action<T>`, since other code is dependant on this strong typed delegate.

In this example, I **know** the method is at least an `Action<object>`.

The following code improves on the original `CreateDelegate` in two ways:

- It is generic now, instead of passing type as a first parameter.
- It does conversion to suitable lower types when possible.

This is the first time for me working with expression trees, so I don't know whether what I'm doing is correct or the best approach. I based this implementation on [an article by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx) (without fully understanding it :)), but the code seems to be working!

```
/// <summary>
///   A generic helper class to do common
///   <see cref = "System.Delegate">Delegate</see> operations.
/// </summary>
/// <author>Steven Jeuris</author>
public static class DelegateHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   The name of the Invoke method of a Delegate.
    /// </summary>
    const string InvokeMethod = "Invoke";

    /// <summary>
    ///   Get method info for a specified delegate type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "delegateType">The delegate type to get info for.</param>
    /// <returns>The method info for the given delegate type.</returns>
    public static MethodInfo MethodInfoFromDelegateType( Type delegateType )
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
            delegateType.IsSubclassOf( typeof( MulticastDelegate ) ),
            "Given type should be a delegate." );

        return delegateType.GetMethod( InvokeMethod );
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Creates a delegate of a specified type that represents the specified
    ///   static or instance method, with the specified first argument.
    ///   Conversions are done when possible.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name = "T">The type for the delegate.</typeparam>
    /// <param name = "firstArgument">
    ///   The object to which the delegate is bound,
    ///   or null to treat method as static
    /// </param>
    /// <param name = "method">
    ///   The MethodInfo describing the static or
    ///   instance method the delegate is to represent.
    /// </param>
    public static T CreateCompatibleDelegate<T>(
       object firstArgument,
       MethodInfo method )
    {
        MethodInfo delegateInfo = MethodInfoFromDelegateType( typeof( T ) );

        ParameterInfo[] methodParameters = method.GetParameters();
        ParameterInfo[] delegateParameters = delegateInfo.GetParameters();

        // Convert the arguments from the delegate argument type
        // to the method argument type when necessary.
        ParameterExpression[] arguments =
            (from delegateParameter in delegateParameters
             select Expression.Parameter( delegateParameter.ParameterType ))
             .ToArray();
        Expression[] convertedArguments =
            new Expression[methodParameters.Length];
        for ( int i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; ++i )
        {
            Type methodType = methodParameters[ i ].ParameterType;
            Type delegateType = delegateParameters[ i ].ParameterType;
            if ( methodType != delegateType )
            {
                convertedArguments[ i ] =
                    Expression.Convert( arguments[ i ], methodType );
            }
            else
            {
                convertedArguments[ i ] = arguments[ i ];
            }
        }

        // Create method call.
        ConstantExpression instance = firstArgument == null
            ? null
            : Expression.Constant( firstArgument );
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
            instance,
            method,
            convertedArguments
            );

        // Convert return type when necessary.
        Expression convertedMethodCall = 
            delegateInfo.ReturnType == method.ReturnType
                ? (Expression)methodCall
                : Expression.Convert( methodCall, delegateInfo.ReturnType );

        return Expression.Lambda<T>(
            convertedMethodCall,
            arguments
            ).Compile();
    }
}
```

So, did I do this the easiest/best way? Am I doing something completely unnecessary? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use such delegates? You're mentioning that it is generic but couldn't you simply use delegates constructor like so: `Action<object> execute = new Action(_owner.SomeMethod)`?

Comment: @Snowbear: This is reflection, `method` is a `MethodInfo`.

Comment: Do you mean that entrance point to your code will be a reflection? So you won't know method you need at compile-time?

Comment: The `MethodInfo` is known, the instance (in this scenario) is known but the type of it unkown. By using applied attributes to a class I known which method is desired, and can retrieve the `MethodInfo`. That's the specific scenario, but in the general case, I **convert a MethodInfo into a delegate**. Read the intro of [Jon Skeet's article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx) for more information. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying some extra [LINQ 4.0 Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) magic, I was able to reduce the code to the following. Anyone sees any more improvements? IMHO this is already a bit clearer.

```
public static T CreateCompatibleDelegate<T>( object instance, MethodInfo method )
{
    MethodInfo delegateInfo = MethodInfoFromDelegateType( typeof( T ) );

    var methodTypes = method.GetParameters().Select( m => m.ParameterType );
    var delegateTypes = delegateInfo.GetParameters().Select( d => d.ParameterType );

    // Convert the arguments from the delegate argument type
    // to the method argument type when necessary.
    var arguments = methodTypes.Zip( delegateTypes, ( methodType, delegateType ) =>
    {
        ParameterExpression delegateArgument = Expression.Parameter( delegateType );
        return new
        {
            DelegateArgument = delegateArgument,
            ConvertedArgument = methodType != delegateType
                            ? (Expression)Expression.Convert( delegateArgument, methodType )
                            : delegateArgument
        };
    } ).ToArray();

    // Create method call.;
    MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
        instance == null ? null : Expression.Constant( instance ),
        method,
        arguments.Select( a => a.ConvertedArgument )
        );

    // Convert return type when necessary.
    Expression convertedMethodCall = delegateInfo.ReturnType == method.ReturnType
                                ? (Expression)methodCall
                                : Expression.Convert( methodCall, delegateInfo.ReturnType );

    return Expression.Lambda<T>(
        convertedMethodCall,
        arguments.Select( a => a.DelegateArgument )
        ).Compile();
}
```

At first I got the dreaded *"variable .. of type ... referenced from scope '' but it is not defined."* exception, but after some pondering I realized I had to add `ToArray()` after the `Zip()` statement to make sure the delegate arguments would already be defined. Powerful stuff this [deferred execution](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/linq-and-deferred-execution-of-queries/), but apparently also a source for errors. I got the same exception when running smartcaveman's latest update, which is perhaps due to a similar mistake.

---

Writing a custom Zip which takes three arguments removes the need of the anonymous type. Writing the Zip is really easy, [as documented by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-35-zip.aspx).

```
public static T CreateCompatibleDelegate<T>( object instance, MethodInfo method )
{
    MethodInfo delegateInfo = MethodInfoFromDelegateType( typeof( T ) );

    var methodTypes = method.GetParameters().Select( m => m.ParameterType );
    var delegateTypes = delegateInfo.GetParameters().Select( d => d.ParameterType );
    var delegateArguments = delegateTypes.Select( Expression.Parameter ).ToArray();

    // Convert the arguments from the delegate argument type
    // to the method argument type when necessary.
    var convertedArguments = methodTypes.Zip(
        delegateTypes, delegateArguments,
        ( methodType, delegateType, delegateArgument ) =>
            methodType != delegateType
                ? (Expression)Expression.Convert( delegateArgument, methodType )
                : delegateArgument );

    // Create method call.
    MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
        instance == null ? null : Expression.Constant( instance ),
        method,
        convertedArguments
        );

    // Convert return type when necessary.
    Expression convertedMethodCall = delegateInfo.ReturnType == method.ReturnType
                                ? (Expression)methodCall
                                : Expression.Convert( methodCall, delegateInfo.ReturnType );

    return Expression.Lambda<T>(
        convertedMethodCall,
        delegateArguments
        ).Compile();
}
```

Comment: If I understood this correctly, I would need to know in advance, the signature of the delegate (that matches the target method(s) signature). What if I don't know it before hand? In my use case, I am reading a file with "method calls" in each line. For example, DoThis(1,2); DoThat(3,4,"test"). I am able to execute them now using Method.Invoke, in fact caching then into a dictionary <String,Action> where the method invoke call, is wrapped further by an Action (e.g. Action act = ()=> methodInfo.Invoke({1,2}). I'm wondering if I could expand this delegate idea further for my use-case.

Comment: I wrote more info on this use case here: ["Creating delegates during reflection for unknown types"](https://whatheco.de/2011/05/25/creating-delegates-during-reflection-for-unknown-types/), ["Creating delegates during reflection with unbound instances"](https://whatheco.de/2011/05/30/creating-delegates-during-reflection-with-unbound-instances/), and ["Casting to less generic types"](https://whatheco.de/2011/07/02/casting-to-less-generic-types/).

Comment: However, I doubt what I describe here (and in the blog posts) is relevant to you. If all you are interested in is calling the methods and their full type definition is known (no casting is needed), then you can just use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` I start the post with. The result of that function would be the `Delegate` you store in your dictionary. The example you state does not make clear why the method signature would be unknown; you have the `MethodInfo`, no?

Comment: Yes, after reflection, the method signature is known, and in fact, I am able to generate a delegate of Action<T1,T2,...Tn> type matching the method signature, by calling Expression.GetActionType(types.ToArray()), where types is from methodInfo.GetParameters() . In theory, this would be the type I would use in your method above (CreateCompatibleDelegate). Where I'm lost next, is that how I then "feed" my string method call into this delegate, so I can cache that specific method call (cache this: Action act = () => newlycreatedDelegate("DoThis(1,2)"))

Comment: Another way (or my other problem), is that when I make the call to the generic method CreateCompatibleDelegate<T>( object instance, MethodInfo method ), when I don't know T until runtime. I am able to programmatically obtain it, but I can't dynamically supply it to this method. T must be known at compile time.

Comment: Why are you trying to cache the method including specific values for the parameters? I thought you were trying to cache the method (by name, for now presuming you do not support method overloading). As far as I understand what you are trying to do you do not need what I did in this post here. You should parse the parameters according to what is expected for the method name, and pass that to your cached delegate; the one you are already able to generate. You do not need method above, which I created for when "other code is dependant on this strong typed delegate" but exact type is not known.

Comment: Put differently: all this code does is generate a method which does the appropriate type conversions, assuming these are possible, thereby resulting in a delegate with different type signatures.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like naming your first argument `firstArgument` will cause more confusion than it's worth. I would offer 2 overloads for this method.

```
// This overload will simply pass null to the main overload 
// for the sake of convenience.
public static T CreateCompatibleDelegate<T>(MethodInfo method)

// I feel like the name 'instance' really makes it clear
// what the parameter means.
public static T CreateCompatibleDelegate<T>(object instance, MethodInfo method)
```

Comment: You are actually really right about that. :O I just copy pasted it [from the info on CreateDelegate from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx) for consistency. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I'm missing something, but this doesn't look like it adds anything to doing

```
 Expression<Action<T,TArg1,TArg2>> lambda = 
      (instance,arg1,arg2) => instance.CallSomeMethod(arg1,arg2);
 var delegate = lambda.Compile();
```

If the only problem is getting the delegate to accept something without knowing the type then all you have to do is

```
 Action<object> ConvertToUntyped<T>(Action<T> action){
      return o => action((T)o);
 }
```

If you need to get the `MethodInfo` for some other reason you can always get the `(MethodCallExpression)Expression<TDelegate>.Expression`.  I don't know your use case, but from my similar experience it looks like you are trying to rebuild some functionality that is already there for you.

I'd also like to add that, *as a general rule*, **if you are setting out to optimize Jon Skeet's C# code, you are probably wasting your time**.

**EDIT**
Using the non-generic lambda expression you have to write less code, and you could probably event cut this down.  I wrote an example for you below.  However, I'm still not sure I understand why you are trying to do this.

```
        var instanceParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(method.DeclaringType, "Instance");
        var argumentParameterExpressions = method.GetParameters().Select(x => Expression.Parameter(x.ParameterType, x.Name));
        var delegateParameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
        delegateParameters.Add(instanceParameterExpression);
        delegateParameters.AddRange(argumentParameterExpressions);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Call(instanceParameterExpression, method, argumentParameterExpressions.Cast<Expression>()),
            delegateParameters.ToArray());
```

### UPDATE

the method below will make a delegate with all object parameters.  I do see what you are getting at now, but I don't think it is a good idea at all.  You have a minimal performance benefit over just using `Action<object> action = arg => bleh.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod").Invoke(new[]{arg});`, and a huge amount of excess complexity.  Furthermore, you are not even using the benefit of strong typing, and you will lose some of the performance benefit whenever you use this on methods with ValueType parameters, (boxing/unboxing).  In theory, this could make something faster, but I think the real world scenarios you will find to apply it this way will be very rare, and won't be worth it.

```
    public Delegate CreateDelegateWithObjectParameters(object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters()
            .Select(parameterInfo => new
            {
                MethodParameterType = parameterInfo.ParameterType,
                DelegateParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), parameterInfo.Name)
            })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.DelegateParameter,
                MethodParameter = Expression.Convert(x.DelegateParameter, x.MethodParameterType)
            });
        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = instance == null
                                                        ? Expression.Call(methodInfo, parameters.Select(x => x.MethodParameter).ToArray())
                                                        : Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(instance), methodInfo, parameters.Select(x => x.MethodParameter).ToArray());
        return Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression, parameters.Select(x => x.DelegateParameter).ToArray()).Compile();
    }
```

Comment: _"which allows to create a delegate by using reflection"_ ... I only have `MethodInfo`. Thanks for the input though. ;p

Comment: @Steven, do you have an instance of the object or just the `MethodInfo`?  How did you get the `MethodInfo`? From where/why are you making this call?

Comment: The MethodInfo is known, the instance (in this scenario) is known but the type of it unkown. By using applied attributes to a class I known which method is desired, and can retrieve the MethodInfo. That's the specific scenario, but in the general case, I convert a MethodInfo into a delegate. Read the intro of Jon Skeet's article for more information. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: @Steven, (1) You can get the type from `MethodInfo.DeclaringType`, (2) Is the method a static method or an instance method?  Because, if you want to get a delegate to a method on an instance, then you also need to construct the instance, (3) I've read the article several times and I just reviewed the intro - I'm still not clear on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @smartcaveman: (1) K, I know the `Type` as in, I have the Type object, which is where I get the `MethodInfo` from in the first place. But I don't have the type at compile time so I can do `instance.CallSomeMethod(arg1,arg2);`. (2) It can be both, check the documentation on firstArgument. (3) Take a look at where the original [CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx) is used. It does the exact same thing, but allows non-specific types. This code is somehow different than the article since I don't allow to pass an instance at runtime.

Comment: @Steven, Are you familiar with non-generic `Expression.Lambda()` factory method?  I think that using that with a call to `Compile()` does what you are looking for.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268052.aspx

Comment: In what way does that improve on my last line (the return statement of the function) which uses the generic Lambda() call?

Comment: It seems like it would save you a lot of unnecessary code, since you aren't able to take advantage of having/don't need  a strongly typed delegate

Comment: I need a strongly typed delegate. (`Action<object>` in this case) Furthermore, I don't see how constructing the body and parameters would be any different. The conversions are necessary because Expression.Call() would throw an `ArgumentException` otherwise.

Comment: As for the `.Cast<Expression>`, I'm not just converting the types to `Expression`, I construct expressions which convert the arguments from the delegate type to the method type (both not known at compile time).

Comment: If the method's parameter type is assignable from the type of the argument that you are passing it, but the type is not exactly the same, then there will be no exception.  Look at the sample code I posted in the edit.  It returns a type of `Delegate`, but you can cast it to the type of delegate that you would get from the method signature and it will compile. So if you used the `MethodInfo` from `Something.VoidMethod()` you would get `Delegate`, that you could make strongly typed by calling `(Action<Something>)yourDelegate)`

Comment: @Steven, I used `Cast<Expression>` because that is what the `Call` method requires.  `ParameterExpression` is derived from `Expression`, so there really isn't much going on there.  By method type, do you mean the object with the method or the return value?

Comment: @Steven, one of us is clearly misunderstanding something.  Maybe when you've worked out a more concrete use case, then the advantage of what you are doing will be more obvious.  I hope I've at least helped you to think about it in a different way - good luck

Comment: @smartcaveman: I need `Action<object>`. Perhaps you understand the code better if you try to get the sample provided to work. `DelegateCommand<T>()` takes `Action<T>` as a first parameter. `_owner` is an `object` and `method` is `MethodInfo`. The type of the argument of the method isn't just `object`, but more specific.

Comment: @Steven, `Action<object> GetActionOfObject<T>(Action<T> actionOfT){ return x => actionOfT((T)x); }`

Comment: @smartcaveman: _"By method type, do you mean the object with the method or the return value?"_ I mean the type of the argument of the method. By delegate type I mean the type of the argument of the delegate.

Comment: @Steven, methods and delegates can both take multiple arguments with different types.

Comment: @smartcaveman: and where does `actionOfT` come from? That's the exact thing which is being constructed! I mean, try to get this code to work: `Action<object> compatibleExecute =
    DelegateHelper.CreateCompatibleDelegate<Action<object>>( _owner, method );
DelegateCommand<object> command =
    new DelegateCommand<object>( compatibleExecute, canExecute );
`

Comment: @Steven, It seems like I would need (1) the class definition for `DelegateCommand`, (2) the class definition for `_owner` with the (3) method signature for `method`, (4) a criteria for what it means for your code to "work"

Comment: @smartcaveman: I gave those before. (1) `DelegateCommand<T>( Action<T> param )` (2, 3) _owner can be any object, let's say an instance from `class Bleh { public void SomeMethod(string s) { } }`, but do remember, you don't know this at compile time. (4) For it to work, making it compile is just fine, what it does is irrelevant.

Comment: @Steven, Where does the value for `s` in `SomeMethod` come from?

Comment: @smartcaveman: That's totally irrelevant, and unknown, it's a public method, it can come from anywhere. I believe I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Steven, How do you expect to get an `Action<object>`, when the object parameter has to be an instance of `Bleh`, and `SomeMethod` requires a string?  You are trying to get a delegate which requires a single parameter for an action that has two parameters (the `Bleh` instance and the string `s`).

Comment: Oops, ofcourse it needs to be able to run as well, I mean, if it doesn't throw an exception at runtime, it's ok. ;p

Comment: Who said the object parameter is an instance of `Bleh`, or two parameters? The returned delegate should execute the given method on the given instance.

Comment: @Steven, dude you did.  "_owner can be any object, let's say an instance from class Bleh"

Comment: @smartcaveman: I thought you were referring to the template parameter (`Action<object>`), which ofcourse didn't make any sense. `_owner` is an instance of `Bleh` yes. I'll update the question with a compileable example as an attempt to clarify things. ;p

Comment: @smartcaveman: Give the updated example another look, I hope the intent is clear now. I'm hoping you'll have an 'aha-erlebnis' ;p

Comment: @Steven,  I don't have edit permissions on this site, but you clearly meant `bleh.GetType().GetMethod()`

Comment: @Steven, now I get what you're trying to do - give me a couple min.

Comment: @smartcaveman: Regarding to your update, I actually never benchmarked this, but you are the one which said to not question Jon Skeet. ;p _"using reflection takes over 600 times as long"_, _"the whole point of the exercise was to avoid invoking methods by reflection"_. He talks of a considerable speed gain over `Invoke()`. I'll benchmark it at some point, and write a blog post about it if the results are worthwile, I'll include the edge cases you mentioned, thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: P.s.: And I just ran your code, it gives an exception on the `Compile()` line: "variable .. of type ... referenced from scope '' but it is not defined. Furthermore your code allows less strong typing than mine. I still allow to use e.g. `Action<string>` in the given sample if I know it is at least that.