# Generic BinaryReader/Writer Read/Write methods

Tags: c#

I have an extension that implements all the BinaryReader/BinaryWriter in the Stream class. I want to create generic methods for them. Is there a nicer way of doing this?

```
public static void Write<T>(this Stream stream, T num)
{
    if (num is byte)
    {
        stream.Write((byte)(object)num);
    }
    else if (num is Int16)
    {
        stream.Write((Int16)(object)num);
    }
    else if (num is Int32)
    {
        stream.Write((Int32)(object)num);
    }
}

public static T Read<T>(this Stream stream)
{
    object ret = null;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
        ret = stream.ReadInt8();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int16))
        ret = stream.ReadInt16();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int32))
        ret = stream.ReadInt32();

    if (ret == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to read type - " + typeof(T));
    return (T)ret;
}
```

Now using this for the Read method.

```
static Dictionary<Type, Func<Stream, object>> ReadFuncs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Stream, object>>()
{
    {typeof(bool), s => s.ReadBoolean()},
    {typeof(byte), s => s.ReadInt8()},
    {typeof(Int16), s => s.ReadInt16()},
    {typeof(Int32), s => s.ReadInt32()},
    {typeof(Int64), s => s.ReadInt64()},
    {typeof(string), s => s.ReadString()},
};
public static T Read<T>(this Stream stream)
{
    if (ReadFuncs.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        return (T)ReadFuncs[typeof(T)](stream);

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you defined more write methods than this? Otherwise the `Write()` would call itself recursively infinitely. You probably have overloads for every supported type, **making the generic write method superfluous**. This would also explain the weird casting you are doing. I'm guessing an overloaded function with a specific type has precedence over a generic method, which is why it could work. This however, doesn't make it a clean solution.

Your `Read()` method seems to be more useful. Instead of throwing a `ArgumentException` I would prefer throwing a `NotSupportedException`.

As a sidenote, are you sure you want to make these extension methods of `Stream` and not some more specific stream? Stream can be **any** type of stream.

---

In what way is this an improvement over using `BinaryWriter`/`BinaryReader`? For the purposes I gather from your code I would only create a `Read<T>` extension method for BinaryReader.

If you feel like experimenting a bit, there might be a more performant/cleaner solution, although you'll have to benchmark to be sure. You could create a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>` to hold a matching 'reader' for every type. Initializing the delegates to store in this dictionary is the tough part, on which information can be found [in this article](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx). Most likely this is not worth the effort, although it still is a very interesting article. :) Be sure to also check out the same solution implemented by using Expression Trees in the comments of the article. For a similar implementation example I did, check out [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1070/2254) I posted on Code Review.

Comment: Well BinaryReader/Writer both take a Stream so I figured I would make the extension for Stream. The Write is really just because I want to do Write<byte>(5) instead of Write((byte)5). Is there any nicer way to do the Read function though?

Comment: @High: I updated my answer with a possible alternate solution, although for the small amount of supported types from BinaryReader, your current implementation is probably better.

Comment: I don't think I will end up using the Write generic but I still created an extension for regular Write. Reason is because it does not require you to create an instance of an object to read from a stream. Also BinaryReader/Writer both Close the stream when they are disposed which I do not like. I updated my question with what I am assuming your second suggestion is.

Comment: @High: Ow .. that makes a lot more sense, .. i was trying to make things too complicated. ;p Yes that is along the lines I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I know your trying to simplify your code, but I think it will be better to go the opposite way, avoid generic types, and doing specific type procedures:

```
public static void WriteByte(this Stream stream, byte num) { ... }
public static void WriteInt16(this Stream stream, Int16 num) { ... }
public static void WriteInt32(this Stream stream, Int32 num) { ... }
```

Why. Because its very easy to call the wrong method, calling "Write(<int32>)" instead of "Write(<byte>)". And in some scenario, the developer may not treat those integer types as the same.

Comment: The generics are separate from the other Write methods so I am not worried about calling the wrong one. Also WriteByte is not possible due to the fact that Stream already has a method by that name that returns an integer.